# Will Qt's Signal and Slots system work if a heap-allocated object gets destroyed and the pointer reassigned?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots

I've a signal and slot connection like this:

```
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
//...
connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), scene, SLOT(doSomething(int)));
//...
delete scene;
scene = new QGraphicsScene;
//...
```

`scene` is a `QGraphicsScene*`. At one point I want to delete the scene and replace it with another `QGraphicsScene`. Hence the location where `scene` points to will change.

Will the signals still work and be rerouted to the new scene?

Comment: Note: you should use `deleteLater()` instead of `delete` on a dynamically allocated `QObject` (`QGraphicsScene` inherits from `QObject`)

Answer (score 2):

Signals and slots involve instances of classes.  Whenever you connect a signal to a slot, two instances of `QObject` derived classes are involved (`connect` requires two pointers to `QObject` to work).

If you are dealing with a new instance of a scene, you have to connect your slots to this new instance. The same applies for the slots of the new scene, that must be bound to... well, whatever makes sense in your software.

Answer (score 2):

destruction of `QObject` causes all its signals and slots to be automatically disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the signals still work and be rerouted to the new scene?

No, they won't be, because the fact that you re-create a scene is only relevant to you. From Qt's perspective, you're creating a completely new, unrelated object. There's no link of any sort between the "old" scene and the "new" scene - other than in your mind, that is.

But you don't need a new scene. You can clear an existing one:

```
#include "MyWidget_ui.h"

class MyWidget : public QWidget { // Not QMainWindow unless you need it
  Ui::MyWidget ui; // You hold the ui by value.
  QGraphicsScene m_scene;
public:
  MyWidget(QWidget * parent = 0) :
    QWidget(parent)
  {
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.comboBox, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged,
            &m_scene, &QGraphicsScene::doSomething);
  }
  void test() {
    m_scene.clear();
    // scene is ready to use
  }
};
```